# Obout Calendar Control not working in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, date, calendar, obout

Has anybody found that the Obout Calendar control has stopped working in the latest Google Chrome update (17.0.963.56 m)?

We have an active licence with Obout, but following two emails and two telephone calls we have yet to receive a response or even an acknowledgement that an issue exists. Anyone using the latest version of Chrome can replicate the issue on the published examples:

http://www.obout.com/calendar/calendar_live_styles.aspx?style=default

Try paging through the months a few times and you should eventually see the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: this is not a Date object.

If anybody has a workaround or can shed light on the matter I would love to hear from you. At the moment it has crippled our live site and we are frantically looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The new version of the Obout Calendar has been released today:
http://www.obout.com/calendar/changelog.aspx

It contains the fix for the latest Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the problem and am also waiting to hear back from Obout. Have sent 3 emails and as yet nothing. I have only just bought the suite this week! and am hoping that this difficulty in getting a response is just my lack of using the correct channels.

Comment: I have now received a reply from Obout, they have replicated the issue and are investigating further. Incidentally I approached them as a new customer, any attempt to contact them as an existing customer yielded no response...Make of that what you will :)

I now believe this is due to an issue with the latest Chrome build for Windows 7.

http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=1945

Answer (score 0):

OK Problem Solved!...Obout have just emailed me a revised DLL. Happy to forward this if anybody requires.